# AttributeError when splitting a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, mcafee

I have a `dict` object in which I'm trying to parse out and capture only a part of the string.

I'm using McAfee EPO Python API's and can grab results of a query, but I don't think that is relevant to this question.

Here is the strings in the objects (multiple lines of similar content).  What I'm after is extracting the `'WORKSTATION001'` text from this string.

```
{u'EPOLeafNode.NodeName': u'WORKSTATION001'}
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
for system in epoSystems:
    computerName = system.rstrip().split('u')
    print computerName
```

This results in:

```
    computerName = system.rstrip().split('u')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Any ideas on how to grab just that string?

Comment: I don't think you have a string -- you have a dictionary in which the strong you want is a value. Access it with its corresponding key: `system[u'EPOLeafNode.NodeName']`.

Comment: You don't have the string `"{u'EPOLeafNode.NodeName': u'WORKSTATION001'}"`, you just have the dictionary `{u'EPOLeafNode.NodeName': u'WORKSTATION001'}`. So just do `system[u'EPOLeafNode.NodeName']`, or `system.values()[0]`, or whatever.

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear—`system` isn't a string—what part don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick responses.  Referencing via system[u'EPOLeafNode.NodeName'] did the trick.

Updated (working) code:

```
for system in epoSystems:
    computerName = system[u'EPOLeafNode.NodeName']
    print computerName
```